# Android crashing after upgrade to Expo 48

Tags: android, react-native, expo

After I upgraded the Expo version to Expo 48, the Android app started crashing on opening.
The iOS is working just fine.

This is the error from the Android console:

```
java_vm_ext.cc:577] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetObjectRefType called with pending exception expo.modules.kotlin.exception.MissingTypeConverter: Cannot find type converter for 'expo.modules.kotlin.Promise'.
    java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at expo.modules.kotlin.types.TypeConverter expo.modules.kotlin.types.TypeConverterProviderImpl.obtainTypeConverter(kotlin.reflect.KType) (TypeConverterProvider.kt:116)...
```

How can I resolve this?

EDIT:

The current workaround is to downgrade the `expo-modules-core` to version `1.2.4`.

```
"resolutions": { "expo-modules-core": "1.2.4" }
```

Comment: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/21711